# How to determine when chef last converged on a node?

Tags: chef-infra

I am using Chef `11.12.4`. For a given node, I would like to know when it last converged. I found [a blog post](http://jtimberman.housepub.org/blog/2013/02/16/last-check-in-time-for-nodes/) about finding `ohai_time`, but it's not clear to me that it's necessarily the same value as last converge time.

The reason I want to know this is because I uploaded a new cookbook version, but I'm not seeing the change taking affect on my nodes. I want to know if converge is not running, or if converge has run, but my cookbook contained an error.

It would also be nice to know what the status of the last converge was.

I'm hoping for something like this:

```
$ knife node converge-status my-node-name
my-node-name successfully converged at 1:23:45 UTC.
```

Does this exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `knife status` command which follows with a search query to know what nodes to return the status for: `knife status 'role:xyz'`

Answer (score 1):

If you have the hostname with you, you can also check like below

```
knife status 'hostname:<yourHostName>'
```